# How to send 802.15.4 packets using XBee S2?

Tags: xbee

I did a quick search but I could not find the answers that I wanted.

I have been playing around with 2 XBee S2 modules and both are configured to be API mode 2. I have tried sending and receiving Zigbee packets using XCTU without any problems. However when I try to send 802.15.4 packets using XCTU, the other XBee does not seem to receive it. Is it suppose to be like this or am I suppose to configure something?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more details on the frame types you're using, and what you mean by "802.15.4" packets?  The XBee S1 uses 802.15.4, but the S2 forms a ZigBee mesh network and (as I recall) supports a different set of API frame types.  Are you using frame types listed on the XBee S2 documentation?

Comment: I am using the data frames under the 802.15.4. From the XCTU, using the frame generator tool, i have tried the following frame types under the 802.15.4 protocol: (a) 0x00 - Tx (Transmit) Request: 64-bit address (b) 0x01 - Tx (Transmit) Request: 16-bit address. I have not looked into the XBee S2 documentation.